# Get random button and set specific value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I recently have a problem with getting random buttons and setting value to it. I found this solution:

```
            WordQuestion wordQuestion = dataSnapshot.getValue(WordQuestion.class);
            int length = wordQuestion.getCorrectAnswer().length();

            buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>(length);

            Button[] buttons = new Button[]{
                    b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12
            };

            buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>(length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){

                Button chosenButton;

                do {
                    chosenButton = buttons[random.nextInt(buttons.length)];
                } while (buttonList.contains(chosenButton));

                buttonList.add(chosenButton);
            }

            for (Button button : buttonList
                 ) {

                button.setText("9");
            }
```

It worked, but it's setting a single value to all buttons. I want to set a specific value to each button chosen. Is it possible?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the most elegant approach. If the specific value you want to set is a sequence (for example 1 to 12) then you can try this,

```
int i = 1; 
for (Button button : buttonList) {

 button.setText(Integer.toString(a));
 a++; 

}
```

Or if you want to set random values (for example between 1 and 12) use this instead,

```
for (Button button : buttonList) {
 int a = (int) (Math.random()*((12-1)+1))+1;
 button.setText(Integer.toString(a));
}
```

Comment: I want to set each button text to different firebase values.